# Using Python and requests to get hidden data

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the Bing AFL (Australian Football) predictions from this page
https://www.bing.com/search?q=afl+predictions&go=Search&qs=bs&form=QBRE

As you can see, the games are shown by date and you can see each date by clicking on the tabs, as shown below.

[image]

I have written a script that can scrape and parse the page however it can only scrape the initial tab that opens with the page because that is all that is included in the source code.

Looking at the source code, the other tabs dont exist within the code until they are clicked on.

I would like to get the source code using requests that includes the data in the tabs of the next few dates.

Sorry if this doesn't completely make sense. Is anyone able to give some direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Capture the ajax request and you can see the pages return in lxml.

Comment: @M.Leung sorry, I'm not entirely sure what this means or how to do it.

Comment: You could open your browser dev tools and go to the network tab and click on the tab. It should show the request and the results.

Comment: @CoryMadden thanks, i have had a look at the network tab. I can't find anything that I would think would be useful. Are you able to provide a little more guidance?